# Why does the Scala compiler fail with missing parameter type for filter with JavaSparkContext?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to add `filter` as shown in [the examples](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) to my program:

```
val logFile = "/tmp/master.txt"
val sc = new JavaSparkContext("local[4]", "Twitter Analyzer", "/home/welcome/Downloads/spark-1.1.0/",Array("target/scala-2.10/Simple-assembly-0.1.0.jar"))
val twitterFeed = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()

while (iterator.hasNext) {
  val value = iterator.next()
  val numAs = twitterFeed.filter(line => line.contains(value))
  numAs.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/output/positive/" + value)
}
```

I get the compilation error as follows:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/siva/file1/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/siva/file1/src/main/scala/com/chimpler/example/twitter/Tweet.scala:27: missing parameter type
[error]     val numAs = twitterFeed.filter(line => line.contains(value))
[error]                                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed 19 Sep, 2014 1:31:26 PM
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is `twitterFeed`? In the example you linked file is some collection of strings, in your case is something different, you should edit your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: @EndeNeu Even if i use the same line as given in the example val file = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
val errors = file.filter(line => line.contains("ERROR")) it still gives the same error at the same place.

Comment: "A Java-friendly version of SparkContext that returns JavaRDDs and _works with Java collections_ instead of Scala ones." This is the [API description for JavaSparkContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html). Try SparkContext instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As @groverboy advised in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929231/missing-parameter-type-while-using-filter-in-scala#comment40592396_25929231) you should really be using [org.apache.spark.SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) instead. Spark Programming Guide's [Initializing Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#initializing-spark) is also clear on this.

```
import org.apache.spark._

val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[4]")
  .setAppName("Twitter Analyzer")
  .setSparkHome("/home/welcome/Downloads/spark-1.1.0/")
  .setJars(Seq("target/scala-2.10/Simple-assembly-0.1.0.jar"))
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

The reason for this is the type inference in Scala that needs type context to infer the type of `line` parameter.

```
val numAs = twitterFeed.filter(line => line.contains(value))
```

It's clearly of `String` type, but using the Java version of SparkContext - [JavaSparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html) - you simply lose the type information.

Provided you use `SparkContext` the above line could be further simplified to:

```
val numAs = twitterFeed.filter(_.contains(value))
```

or even:

```
twitterFeed.filter(_ contains value)
```

All the goodies just `SparkContext` away.

Answer (score 4):

```
val numAs =  twitterFeed.filter((i: String) => i.contains(value))
```

resolved the problem.